# MongoDB index does not reduce nscannedObjects

Tags: mongodb

In MongoDB, I have the following simple query, with an index on postTime:-1. The collection has 100,237 documents.  The explain() says that the query is fully covered by indexes.

Why is it that nScannedObjects is 100,237?  Also, query time is 455ms even though I'm only interested in the first 5 results.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this how MongoDB works? Can someone explain why the indexed query takes so long?

Thanks :) Les

```
db.guestBookPost.find({ postTime : {$gte : 0}, $orderby : { "postTime" : -1}}, {_id:0, >postTime:1}).limit(5).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor postTime_-1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 0,
    "nscannedObjects" : 100237,
    "nscanned" : 100237,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 200474,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 200474,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : true,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 455,
    "indexBounds" : {
    "postTime" : [
            [
                1.7976931348623157e+308,
                0
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "ip-10-245-26-151:27017"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `$orderby` syntax seems to be what's causing it. You can use either:

```
db.guestBookPost.
  find({ postTime : {$gte : 0}}, {_id:0, >postTime:1}).
  sort({postTime: -1}).
  limit(5).
  explain()
```

Or:

```
db.guestBookPost.
  find({ postTime : {$gte : 0}}, {_id:0, >postTime:1}).
  _addSpecial("$orderBy", {postTime: -1}).
  limit(5).
  explain()
```

and it'll work fine. I'm not sure why the $orderby syntax isn't working properly, but either of those approaches should solve it.

Comment: It is a bug, you cannot use `$` operators with function ones

Comment: Thank you, the alternate syntax does work. I have another query question I will post separately.